# How to print a value on the button when it is clicked?

Tags: button, unity-game-engine

I want print a value on the button when it is clicked.How it is possible?

**[Update]**

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 
public class tic : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    void OnGUI() { 
        string value=""; 
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,10,50,50),value)) { 
            value="y"; 
            print ("y"); 
            GUI.Button(new Rect(10,10,50,50),value); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please see the [Unity GUI scripting guide](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/GUIScriptingGuide.html), there is an example of what you want in the first example they show.

Comment: But it is not printing on the button, Its printing on the left bottom of the screen.

Comment: So I'm clear, you want to click a button and have the text show up on the button itself?

Comment: @jerdak: Yes i want to print on the button itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the [Unity gui example](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/GUIScriptingGuide.html) you can modify the button text by storing that text in a variable and changing it when the button is clicked, like so:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GUITest : MonoBehaviour {
    public string ButtonText = "Click Me"
    void OnGUI () {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10,10,150,100), ButtonText )) {
            ButtonText = "Huzzah!";
        }
    }
}
```

The button will first read as "Click Me" then will change once to "Huzzah".

If you don't want to change the actual text in the button it gets a little tougher.  You would need to create a label that sits over the button, I don't recommend going this route.  It won't look nice and the label won't move w/ the button:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GUITest : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool DrawLabel = false;
    public string LabelText = "Huzzah"
    void OnGUI () {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10,10,150,100), "Click Me")) {
            DrawLabel = true;
        }
        if(DrawLabel){
            // use the same rect parameters as you did to create the button
            GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, 150,100), LabelText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RajeshKumar What isn't working exactly?  It might help if your original question included a screenshot, or code, or something to indicate the behaviour you want vs. the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Initially i have a button with null value.After clicking that button some value should be printed on the button itself.

Comment: @RajeshKumar Please include that in your initial question so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class tic : MonoBehaviour {
void OnGUI()
 {
string value="";
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,10,50,50),value))
   {
   value="y";
   print ("y");
   GUI.Button(new Rect(10,10,50,50),value);
   }
}
}

Comment: @RajeshKumar My answer is still correct.  In your code, string value is a local variable, it needs to be declared outside of OnGUI.  Everytime your OnGUI is called, value is set to "" again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this;

```
var ControlsButton = GameObject.Find("ControlsButton");
ControlsButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Accelerometer"
```